# Does a KILL signal exit a process immediately?

Tags: c, linux, signals

I'm working on a server code that uses `fork()` and exec to create child processes. The PID of the child is registered when `fork()` succeeds and cleaned up when the `CHILD` signal has been caught.

If the server needs to stop, all programs are killed, eventually with a KILL signal. Now, this works by means of iterating through all registered PIDs and waiting for the CHILD signal handler to remove the PIDs. This will fail if child program did not exit properly. Therefore I want to use `kill` in combination with `waitpid` to ensure that PID list is cleaned up and log and do some other stuff otherwise.

Consider the next code sample:

```
kill(pid, SIGKILL);
waitpid(pid, NULL, WNOHANG);
```

Excerpt from `waitpid(2)`:

> waitpid(): on success, returns the process ID of the child whose state has changed; if WNOHANG was specified and one or  more  child(ren)
>   specified by pid exist, but have not yet changed state, then 0 is returned.  On error, -1 is returned.

Is the process given by `pid` always gone before the next function kicks in? Will `waitpid` always return `-1` in the above case?

Comment: A KILL signal is rather brutal, why not INT or HUP? And also, what is the return code of the `kill` syscall?

Comment: "waiting for the CHILD signal handler to..." -- There is no signal handler for SIGKILL, you know? All signals except SIGSTOP and SIGKILL will do what's been set by `sigaction` (so for example invoke a handler), or the default. SIGSTOP just stops, and SIGKILL just kills the process. Always. There is no handling or conditional. (The exception being that the `kill` syscall fails because you don't have sufficient rights.)

Comment: @Damon: `SIGKILL` cannot be ignored by the destination process, thats right. But thats not the question/problem. The `kill(2)` system call on the source process can return before the signal is evaluated (by the kernel) in the context of the destination process. `kill(2)` is basically a very simple asynchronous communication and must be treated as such with all implications.

Comment: Yeah, don't use `SIGKILL` except when there is no other choice. If you want to instruct a process to terminate, use `SIGTERM`.

Comment: @fge It *eventually* sends SIGKILL if the child does not responds fast enough on SIGTERM.

Comment: If you’re about to exit the parent anyway, there’s not much point waiting for the children.  Send them a SIGKILL, exit, let init clean up the zombies.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is the process given by pid always gone before the next function kicks in?

There is no guarantee for that. On a multiprocessor your process might be on CPU 0 while the cleanup in the kernel for the killed process takes place on CPU 1. That's a classical race-condition. Even on singlecore processors there is no guarantee for that.

> Will waitpid always return -1 in the above case?

Since it is a race condition - in most cases it perhaps will. But there is no guarantee.

---

Since you are not interested in the status, this semicode might be more appropriate in your case:

```
// kill all childs
foreach(pid from pidlist)
    kill(pid, SIGKILL);

// gather results - remove zombies
while( not_empty(pidlist) )
    pid = waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG);
    if( pid > 0 )
        remove_list_item(pidlist, pid);
    else if( pid == 0 )
        sleep(1);
    else
        break;
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I won't be able to use the suggested code since the SIGCHILD handler removes the items from the pidlist. That leaves me to the option: check if the process is running, remove if not, kill otherwise.

Comment: Simply remove the `WNOHANG` flag and your code will work as expected.

Comment: @Lekensteyn: If there is already a SIGCHLD handler which updates a list, then this handler can call `waitpid` to remove the zombie process. Then the `while` loop only needs to wait for a) all processes dead and buried or b) some timeout for safety.

Answer (score 5):

The `KILL` signal handler will run during the killed processes CPU time. This is potentially much later than your `waitpid` call, especially on a loaded system, so `waitpid` can very well return 0.

Answer (score 0):

JFYI there is also the option of `pidfd_send_signal()`. From the manual:

> The pidfd_send_signal() system call allows the avoidance of race
> conditions that occur when using traditional interfaces (such as
> kill(2)) to signal a process.  The problem is that the
> traditional interfaces specify the target process via a process
> ID (PID), with the result that the sender may accidentally send a
> signal to the wrong process if the originally intended target
> process has terminated and its PID has been recycled for another
> process.  By contrast, a PID file descriptor is a stable
> reference to a specific process; if that process terminates,
> pidfd_send_signal() fails with the error ESRCH.

You can see an example on how to use it [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pidfd_send_signal.2.html).